# Homebrew corrupted; MacOS Big Sur M1 Postgres; can't brew start services postgres, fails with Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Tags: homebrew

My postgres was fine until yesterday, when *all of a sudden* it seems to have zapped itself away.

when I start postgres with

% brew services start postgres

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/jason/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.

`brew uninstall postgress` and `brew reinstall postgres` does not fix the problem.

~~

interestingly `brew doctor` just started giving me this:

```
% brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Your Xcode (12.5) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 13.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix this was to implode my Homebrew completely and re install it.

Following these steps:

1. upgraded to Xcode 13
2. removed homebrew completely
   https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew
   run on command line

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

3. 

it told me that there were a bunch of `/opt/homebrew/*` directories it wouldn't/couln't remove for me, so I removed them manually with `sudo rm -r /opt/homebrew`

4.
Then I restarted my machine and confirmed homebrew was gone.

5.
then I began again with the home brew installation on this page https://brew.sh/

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Once I re-installed posgres, the original symptom seemed to go away.